# Force existing CONFIRMED cognito user back to the UNCONFIRMED state

Tags: amazon-cognito

First a bit of background: In some circumstances I want to force an existing cognito user to re-validate their email address (but not change their password) before they can log in again.

Just setting the `email_verified` to `false` doesn't stop them logging in, so I figured I also need to set their `UserStatus` back to `UNCONFIRMED`. However, I can't see any way of doing this in the API.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but from what I remember and what this [diagram](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html) indicates the transition back to unconfirmed is not possible.

You will have to extend the existing behaviour and state diagram.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't seen this diagram. I already have some custom attributes and triggers to customize the flow so I guess I can add my logic in there, rather than relying on the UNCONFIRMED state